# Intermittent 500 internal server error in images after adding isolation_level to a flask-sqlalchemy app on apache mod_wsgi server

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, mod-wsgi, pyodbc, isolation-level

I am using Apache mod_wsgi in a flask-sqlalchemy, marshamllow application, connecting to a remote ms sql database using pyodbc, recently I was asked to add isolation_level 'SNAPSHOT' and I did that using apply_driver_hacks

```
class SQLiteAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
def apply_driver_hacks(self, app, info, options):
    options.update({
        'isolation_level': 'SNAPSHOT',
    })
    super(SQLiteAlchemy, self).apply_driver_hacks(app, info, options)
```

the project is built to access image blob data from a ms sql server and display on a webpage, soon after adding the isolation level I see internal error generated for every few images, doing a ctrl+f5 displays the image but then there are other images not being displayed and this is in the error log
        mod_wsgi (pid=10694): Exception occurred processing WSGI script
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Transaction failed in database 'testdb' because the statement was run under snapshot isolation but the transaction did not start in snapshot isolation. You cannot change the isolation level of the transaction to snapshot after the transaction has started unless the transaction was originally started under snapshot isolation level. (3951) (SQLExecDirectW)")

edited to add code below:

how would I do that with flask-sqlalchmey when not using create-engine

my app.py file

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config.ProductionConfig')
db.init_app(app)
ma.init_app(app)
```

my model.py file

```
class SQLiteAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
def apply_driver_hacks(self, app, info, options):
    options.update({
        'isolation_level': 'SNAPSHOT',
    })
    super(SQLiteAlchemy, self).apply_driver_hacks(app, info, options)

# To be initialized with the Flask app object in app.py.
db = SQLiteAlchemy()
ma = Marshmallow()
```

Comment: Why not set the isolation level at engine, session or transaction level [as per the official docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#setting-transaction-isolation-levels)?

Comment: how would I do that when using flask-sqlalchemy, I am not using create_engine:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### At Engine Level

If you were using the [declaritive](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/sqlalchemy/) implementation you would have access to the create engine function (and the scoped session one).

But assuming you're using the Flask-SQLAlchemy implementation, this just calls `sqlalchemy.create_engine` under the hood [(on this line)](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/50944e77522d4aa005fc3c833b5a2042280686d3/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L563).

Might be a hack for the latter, as there doesn't seem to be a way to pass engine related options in; they are defined specifically a few lines up at `#558`:

```
options = {'convert_unicode': True}
```

### At Session Level

This looks like it could be slightly easier, because you can pass session options when you initialise SQLAlchemy: [see this line](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/50944e77522d4aa005fc3c833b5a2042280686d3/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L680).  The `create_scoped_session` method expects [a dictionary](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/50944e77522d4aa005fc3c833b5a2042280686d3/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L709) which can be passed to the `__init__` method as `session_options`.

So when you initialise the library you could try something like:

```
db = SQLiteAlchemy(session_options={'isolation_level': 'SNAPSHOT'})
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting this error:
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'isolation_level'

Comment: The same application run on windows on python virtual environment gives no error but on  a centos 7 apache mod_wsgi gives 500 internal server error to few images makes me think it is some setting in the mod_wsgi causing this issue.

Comment: `db = SQLAlchemy(app, session_options={'isolation_level': 'SNAPSHOT'})` didn't throw any errors for me, but might not fit your code layout.

Comment: can you please tell the sqlalchemy version and flask-sqlalchemy version you are using, maybe they matter

Comment: `Flask==1.0.2`, `Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2`,`SQLAlchemy==1.2.15`, `